# Hook fires without seeing module weight

Tags: 8, forms

I have created a module named menu_bold and has dependency over menu_ui. Weight of menu_ui is 0 but menu_bold module has been changed to 1.

Now when the function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter is calling, it is firing first from menu_bold rather than menu_ui, indeed menu_ui has weight 0 and menu_bold has 1.

Why is this happing ?

Comment: Tried refreshing cache?

Comment: Yes I tried but couldn't get any luck

Comment: Is it possible something is messing with the order using hook_module_implements_alter??

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you are asking. Are you asking why the module weight was set to 1, or why module_bold is invoked first? Also, what did you do to check which module is invoked first?

Comment: Hi Kiamlaluno, My question is why hook_form_FORM_ID_alter in menu_bold fires first although it has more weight than menu_ui. I have printed some text in both hook to see which hook fires first and I found menu_bold hook fired it first.